# How to solve $x^6+x^4+x^2=3$

Tags: solution-verification, radicals

So I was yet again scrolling through Youtube to see if there were any math equations that I might be able to solve when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/FLKFp57Zdaw) equation by Sybermath that I thought that I might be able to solve. The equation was

$$\text{Solve: }x^6+x^4+x^2=3$$

which I thought that I might be able to solve. Here is my attempt at solving the equation:

$$\text{Right away we can see that both}$$

$$x=-1$$

$$\text{and}$$

$$x=1$$

$$\text{are solutions to the equation }x^6+x^4+x^2=3$$

$$\text{However, are there any imaginary solutions to the equation?}$$

$$x^6+x^4+x^2=3$$

$$x^2(x^4+x^2+1)=3$$

$$x^2(x^2(x^2+1)+1)=3$$

$$x^2(x^2(x-i)(x+i)+1)=3$$

$$x^2(x-i)(x+i)+1=\frac{3}{x^2}$$

$$x^2(x-i)(x+i)+\frac{x^2}{x^2}=\frac{3}{x^2}$$

$$x^2(x-i)(x+i)+\frac{x^2-3}{x^2}=0$$

$$x^2(x-i)(x+i)+\frac{(x+\sqrt3)(x-\sqrt3)}{x^2}=0$$

$$(x-i)(x+i)=-\frac{x^2-3}{x^4}$$

$$(x-i)(x+i)=-\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{3}{x^4}\right)$$

$$(x-i)(x+i)=-1\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{3}{x^4}\right)$$

$$(x-i)(x+i)=-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}$$

Plugging what we have into the quadratic formula gets us

$$\frac{\pm\sqrt{-4(1)(1)}}{2}=\frac{x^2-3}{x^4}$$

$$\pm i=\frac{x^2-3}{x^4}$$

$$\pm ix^4=x^2-3$$

And plugging what we know here into the quadratic formula gets us

$$\frac{\pm\sqrt{-4(1)(-3)}}{2}=\pm ix^4$$

$$\frac{\pm\sqrt{12}}{2}=\pm ix^4$$

$$\pm\sqrt3=ix^4$$

$$\frac{\sqrt3}{i}=x^4$$

$$-i\sqrt3=x^4$$

Square rooting both sides gets us

$$i\sqrt[4]3=x^2$$

And square rooting again gets us

$$\sqrt[8]3\left(\frac{\sqrt2+i\sqrt2}{2}\right)=x$$

$$\text{Or }\pm\frac{\sqrt[8]3\sqrt2+i\sqrt2}{2}=x$$

**My question**

---

Is my solution correct, or what could I do to attain the correct solution(s) or attain it more easily?

Comment: It looks simpler to let $z=x^2$, making your equation into a cubic, and since we know that $z=1$ is a root of that cubic, we are quickly down to a quadratic.

Comment: I haven't read through everything, but you can make the variable substitution of $x^2=t$ and view this as $t^3+t^2+t-3=0$.  You can use your observation of $t=1$ being one of the solutions to then perform polynomial long division to get $(t-1)(t^2+2t+3)=0$.  Solve $t^2+2t+3=0$ by quadratic formula and you'll have then three solutions for $t$ which work in all.  Square root each and tack on a $\pm$ to call this six solutions to the original equation.

Comment: "$$(x-i)(x+i)=-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x^4}$$Plugging what we have into the quadratic formula gets us$$\frac{\pm\sqrt{-4(1)(1)}}{2}=\frac{x^2-3}{x^4}"$$

Wait, can you explain what you have done here please.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I'm not really sure since I think I just got desperate for a solution, it might/might not be a legal move. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note if you can find $x=1, x=-1$ are roots to the equation, it means

$$x^6+x^4+x^2-3=(x+1)(x-1)P_4(x)$$

You can apply the long division technique, and get

$$P_4(x)=x^4+2x^2+3$$

To find the rest four roots, just solve $P_4(x)=0$, which gives

$$x^4+2x^2+3=(x^2+1)^2+2=0$$
then we get
$$\Rightarrow x^2+1=\pm \sqrt2 i$$

and you proceed from here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: substitute $y=x^2$ to get the equation
$$y^3+y^2+y-3=0$$
And now note that $1$ is a solution to the equation.

Comment: Thanks, however, I had already noted this at the top of the post.

Comment: Yes, but now you can put it in the form $(y-1)P(y)=0$ where $P(y)$ is a second degree polynomial.

Comment: @CrSb0001 You've missed the point, which is that you can divide $y^3+y^2+y-3$ by $y-1$ to get a quadratic equation in $y$, which you can solve using the quadratic formula or by completing the square.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite as

$(x^2)^3-1+x^4-1+x^2-1=0 \\
(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)+(x^2-1)(x^2+1)+x^2-1=0 \\
(x^2-1)(x^4+2x^2+3)=0$

$x^4+2x^2+3=0$ is a quadratic for $u=x^2$